# Action Script 3.0 Play / Pause External SWF file

Tags: flash, action, playback, onpause

I use Flash CS6, AC3, to design Player (swf, and flv).

When test, it loaded SWF, FLV file, and auto play.

BUT, Error, when I add Play/Pause button.

When I click Play/Pause button. Nothing happen ! (Movie still play, not pause)

My code here !

Please, HELP ME ! Thank so much pro !

//

```
public class Player extends MovieClip
{
    //
    var Play_Mode:Boolean = true;

    var URL_File:String = "Swf_FILE.swf";
    var URL_Request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(URL_File);

    var Movie_Clip_Container:MovieClip= new MovieClip();
    var Movie_Clip_Loader:Loader = new Loader();

    //
    public function Player()
    {
        Play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Toggle_Play_Mode);
        Pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Toggle_Play_Mode);


        //
        Movie_Clip_Loader.load(URL_Request);
        Movie_Clip_Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, Movie_Clip_Loaded);

        Movie_Clip_Container.addChildAt(Movie_Clip_Loader, 0);
        addChildAt(Movie_Clip_Container, 0);
    }

    function Movie_Clip_Loaded(event:Event):void
    {

    }

    public function Toggle_Play_Mode(event:Event)
    {
        if (Play_Mode)
        {
            Play_Mode = false;
            Movie_Clip_Container.stop();
        }
        else
        {
            Play_Mode = true;

            Movie_Clip_Container.play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mention also technology

Comment: I use Adobe Flash CS6, and Action Script 3.0.

To design Flash Player (play another SWF, and FLV file).

Please, help me... Thank so much pro !